# getMeasuredWidth() not working

Tags: android

This code is not working well for my nexus 7.First time when i install(debugge)its give me value
"1286" but after close the app and again i start it then give me width "1542" .

i know this one correct code but it is not worked why it give wrong value???

```
ViewTreeObserver vto        =   horizontalLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override

            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                horizontalLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                Log.i("WIDTH","Width "+horizontalLayout.getMeasuredWidth()+" width "+horizontalLayout.getWidth());

            }
        });
```

any idea why it is happened???